# Cholesky/LU decomposition from matrix and its inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, factoring

Usually, we have a matrix $A$ and want to calculate the $LU$ (or sometimes Cholesky, depending on $A$'s properties) decomposition. This is often the hard part. Now, if we have the $LU$ decomposition of $A$, it is easy to calculate $A^{-1}$ (triangular matrices are easy to invert - FW backward substitution is stable and can be parallelized).

Is the other way also possible? I.e. given $A$ and $A^{-1}$, can we calculate the LU decomposition (or Cholesky) of $A$ stable, and easy to parallelize, in a similar way as inverting triangular matrices?

Answer (score 1):

I thought about it for a little while, I can't see it. I can't prove it is impossible, but it is not apparent by elementary arguments. For simplicity of discussion, suppose $A$ admits a $LU$ decomposition.

Consider, $A=LU$ then $A^{-1} = U^{-1}L^{-1}$ so, if I take products of the given $A$ and $A^{-1}$ I can not see how to isolate $L$ and $U$ since $AA^{-1} = LUU^{-1}L^{-1}=I$ yields no insight.

In principle, $A^{-1}$ is the product of elementary matrices. The matrices $E_1, \dots E_k$ accomplish the so-called **forward pass** which gives $ref(A) = E_k \cdots E_1A$ where $ref(A)$ has zeros below the pivot positions. Given $A^{-1}$ exists, each column is a pivot so we can assume that $ref(A) = I + N$ where $N$ is a strictly upper triangular matrix and $I$ is the identity. Next, the Gaussian elimination proceeds to the **backwards pass** which clears out the nontrivial entries in $N$. We can view the backwards pass as multiplication by elementary matrices $E_{k+1}, \dots ,E_{r}$. We find:
$$ E_{r} \cdots E_{k+1}E_{k} \cdots E_{1}A = E_{r} \cdots E_{k+1}ref(A)=I $$
since $rref(A)=I$ given $A^{-1}$ exists. The inverse is unique, so we have
$$ A^{-1} = E_{r} \cdots E_{k+1}E_{k} \cdots E_{1} $$
But, how do we pull-apart the $L$ and $U$ from this list? Given my notation, they are:
$$ U = ref(A) = E_{k} \cdots E_{1}A \qquad \text{and} \qquad L = E_{k+1}^{-1} \cdots E_{r}^{-1} $$
The problem is that $A^{-1}$ has both the forward and backwards pass implicit within it's structure. I can't see how to separate them without some other insight.

Fortunately, we do have a method to factor a matrix $A$ into the $LU$ (or sometimes $PLU$) so... while I like your question, I'm not sure how to go further with it.

Comment: Thanks so far. I don't want to accept it yet, but I upvoted it because it shows the difficulty.

Comment: @Johannes don't accept it, no problem, it's not entirely an answer... there may be no answer, so, feel free to leave it hanging.